# Problem with Mockito, invoking stubbed methods

Tags: java, mockito

I am creating a test class, and when I stub certain methods of the mocked object to return true, when calling another method that checks the one that was stubbed, its result is ignored.

This is the test method:

```
    @Test
    public void AddExistingUser(){
        //Mocking
        mockedManager = mock(UserManager.class);

        //Stubbing
        when(mockedManager.checkUsername("test")).thenReturn(true);
        
        assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> {
            mockedManager.addUser("test", "test");
        });
    }
```

And this is UserManager.addUser:

```
    public void addUser(String username, String password) {
        //Check if the user already exists.
        if (checkUsername(username)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("User already exists.");
        }
        usersData.put(username, hashPassword(password));
        file.writeString(json.toJson(usersData), false);
    }
```

This is UserManager.checkUsername in case it is needed:

```
    public boolean checkUsername(String username) {
        return usersData.containsKey(username);
    }
```

(Where usersData is an ObjectMap<String, String>)

I would expect the test to success since it should return an IllegalArgumentException, however I get "org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Expected java.lang.IllegalArgumentException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `Mockito.mock` you are creating a dummy object with no logic in any of the methods and no real method calls.

With this line, you are telling you mock object, that it should return `true` when the method `checkUsername` with the parameter test is called.

```
when(mockedManager.checkUsername("test")).thenReturn(true);
```

Any other calls of `checkUsername` with any other parameter like `"foo"` or so, will result in returning the default value, that is specified by the mock. Since this method will return `boolean`, `false` should be returned.

For your method `addUser(String, String)` you have not told mockito what to do with this method. That means that there will not be any calls to this method body. You can also find this out, by placing some `System.out.println` in the first line of your method. These calls will not appear in any log.

If you want mockito to call your real method you have two options:

1. Telling mockito to call the real method. This can be done by any of the two forms.

   ```
   when(mockedManager.addUser("test", "test")).thenCallRealMethod();

   doCallRealMethod().when(mockedManager).addUser("test", "test");
   ```

   You just need one of the forms. This will result that every time you call the method `addUser` with the parameters `"test", "test"`, it will call the real method. On any other cases, it will do the default behavior and not calling the real method.
2. Using `Mockito.spy(Object.class)`. With this, you do not need to specify calling the real method, because this is the default behavior. You will either need in your class a no-arguments constructor or create the mock object with an other constructor. Also you need to use the `doXX` methods for mockito, that means your mocked call will look like this.

   ```
   doReturn(true).when(mockedManager).checkUsername("test");
   ```